# How to allow scroll over amCharts on mobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery, amcharts

I'm using amCharts donut charts like this: https://www.amcharts.com/demos/donut-chart/

My JS code to create this chart is:

```js
var results = getJsData().responses;


var chart = AmCharts.makeChart("chartdiv", {
    "type": "pie",
    "startDuration": 0,
    "theme": "light",
    "labelRadius": -35,
    "labelText": "[[percents]]%",
    "addClassNames": true,
    "legend":{
        "position":"bottom",
        "marginRight":100,
        "autoMargins":false
    },
    "innerRadius": "30%",
    "defs": {
        "filter": [{
            "id": "shadow",
            "width": "200%",
            "height": "200%",
            "feOffset": {
                "result": "offOut",
                "in": "SourceAlpha",
                "dx": 0,
                "dy": 0
            },
            "feGaussianBlur": {
                "result": "blurOut",
                "in": "offOut",
                "stdDeviation": 5
            },
            "feBlend": {
                "in": "SourceGraphic",
                "in2": "blurOut",
                "mode": "normal"
            }
        }]
    },
    "dataProvider": results,
    "valueField": "votes",
    "titleField": "response"
});

chart.addListener("init", handleInit);

chart.addListener("rollOverSlice", function(e) {
    handleRollOver(e);
});

function handleInit(){
    chart.legend.addListener("rollOverItem", handleRollOver);
}

function handleRollOver(e){
    var wedge = e.dataItem.wedge.node;
    wedge.parentNode.appendChild(wedge);
}
```

This looks fine, even on mobile devices, but the problem is when I try to do scroll on mobile devices (touching the amChart chart, because this chart occupies much of the screen) nothing happens.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding "panEventsEnabled" property as false?